# What type bulb goes in my chandelier?

Tags: light-fixture, bulb

[image: Socket]

This chandelier had no bulbs when we moved in...guess they couldn’t find replacement either? Please help!

Comment: It is not at all clear what your picture is attempting to show other than a smear and finger print of purple nail polish. Please show another picture that captures more of the fixture so that we can see how the thing is constructed. Then just maybe the picture that you showed will make more sense.

Comment: That appears to be a candelabra base socket missing both a bulb and cardboard candle cover.

Comment: You have some capable powers of observation if you can see where that's candelabra, @Tyson. I would rather see a photo looking down into the socket, with a ruler or tape measure right next to it for scale (it's hard to tell the different Edison sockets apart without a reference for size).

Comment: @Harper, you can see the fake candle cover on the right edge of the picture

Comment: @Jennifer, that writing on the side of the socket is not as useful as you probably (and not unreasonably) think it is. We need to see a view down into the end of the socket.

Comment: @Harper ....assuming it's an Edison socket....

Comment: I'll bet it's an E-12 lamp. 
Googling "ROTCHEN lamp socket" gets you here: https://www.grandbrass.com/category/lamp_sockets-e_12_candelabra_lamp_sockets-e_12_candle_sockets/lamp_sockets-e_12_candelabra_lamp_sockets/
And they seem to look very similar.... who knows if that's coincidence or not? We need better pictures.